# Loading initial values from state in redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to load initial values (that I get from an async call to the server) in a Redux Form, but nothing happens.
The server call works fine (I can see my redux state updating), but the form doesn't display the values.

I read all the questions on stack-overflow, and applied all the solutions but nothing works :

I pass initialValues (which gets updated with the initial values from the async call) through the connect function, and added enableReinitialize: true to reduxForm()

My code is below. I'm not showing the action nor reducer, as I believe they work fine (I use them for other views where there are no issues).

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';

import { BASEURL } from '../config'

import { updateBenefit, fetchBenefit } from '../actions';


class SubsidyTiming extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchBenefit(this.props.match.params.benefit)
  }

  renderField(field) {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>{field.label}</label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type={field.type}
          {...field.input}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  renderSelect(field) {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>{field.label}</label>
        <select
          className="form-control"
          {...field.input}>
            {field.children}
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }

  onSubmit = (values) => {
  this.props.updateBenefit(values, this.props.match.params.benefit, (subsidy_name) => {
    this.props.history.push(`${BASEURL}/benefits`)
  }); }


  render() {
    if (!this.props.initialValues) {
      return (<h1>{I18n.t("loading")}</h1>)
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
          <Field
            label={I18n.t("benefits.new.start.subsidy")}
            name="opening_date"
            type="date"
            component={this.renderField}
          />
          <Field
            label={I18n.t("benefits.new.end.subsidy")}
            name="closing_date"
            type="date"
            component={this.renderField}
          />
          <Field
            label={I18n.t("benefits.new.is_renewable.subsidy")}
            name="is_renewable"
            type="checkbox"
            component={this.renderField}
          />
          <Field
            label={I18n.t("benefits.new.frequency.subsidy")}
            name="frequency"
            type="select"
            component={this.renderSelect}
          >
            <option></option>
            <option value="weekly">{I18n.t("frequency.weekly")}</option>
            <option value="monthly">{I18n.t("frequency.monthly")}</option>
            <option value="quarterly">{I18n.t("frequency.quarterly")}</option>
            <option value="semiannually">{I18n.t("frequency.semiannually")}</option>
            <option value="annually">{I18n.t("frequency.annually")}</option>
          </Field>
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary"
            type="submit"
            disabled={this.props.pristine || this.props.submitting}>
            Sauver et continuer
          </button>
        </form>

      </div>
    )
  }

}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    initialValues: state.benefit
  }
}

export default reduxForm({ form: 'updateSubsidyForm', enableReinitialize: true })(
  connect(mapStateToProps, { updateBenefit, fetchBenefit })(SubsidyTiming)
);
```

Thanks for your help !

---

**EDIT**

Here is my action.js file :

```js
import { APIENDPOINT } from '../config'

export const FETCH_BENEFIT = 'FETCH_BENEFIT'


const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attributes.content.value;


export function fetchBenefit(benefit) {
  const url = `${APIENDPOINT}/${benefit}`
  const promise = fetch(url, { credentials: 'same-origin' }).then(r => r.json())

  return {
    type: FETCH_BENEFIT,
    payload: promise
  }
}

export function updateBenefit(body, name, callback) {
  const promise = fetch(`${APIENDPOINT}/${name}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }).then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => callback(r.name))

  return {
    type: BENEFIT_UPDATED,
    payload: promise
  }
}
```

And my benefit_reducer.js file

```js
import { FETCH_BENEFIT } from '../actions';

export default function(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_BENEFIT: {
      return action.payload
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: initialValues contains `Object` with keys Field.name?

Comment: are the redux key values exactly the same as the names in your fields?

Comment: Can you show us your reducers?

Answer (score 0):

Your component won't re-render on props change (your Redux state will be in the props of your component), unless you tell it to. One way to do this is to initially have your data as `null` in state, fetch it in `componentWillMount()`, use `getDerivedStateFromProps()`, and then render it from state.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  if (props.intialValues !== state.initialValues) {
    return { ...state, initialValues };
  }     

  return null;
}
```

Comment: I thought the same at first, but it looks like his component is stateless.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
I'm a bit new to React, but my understanding is that the Redux Form doesn't catch the initialValues. This is true even when I set arbitrary values, without making an async fetch request. For example if I pass initialValues = {frequency: 'monthly'} in my mapStateToProps function, the form doesn't display it.